# Scaffolding with geometry data in PostgreSql mapping error

Tags: postgresql, geometry, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm trying to do ModelFirst (scaffolding) of an existing bbdd in postgresql with geometry data.

In the VS project I have well installed all the necessary nuget packages (EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore.Design, EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, EntityFrameworkCore.Tools, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design and Npgsql.NetTopologySuite).

In VS PM, when launching the command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=myserver;Database=spatial;Username=postgres;Password=xxxxxxxx" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -Schemas spu -OutputDir Spatials
```

He gives me these exceptions:

> Could not find type mapping for column 'spu.nuts.geom' with data type
>   'geometry(Geometry,4326)'. Skipping column.

And it doesn't map the geometry columns, all rest columns are ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Can I specify scaffolding using NetTopologySuite?

Thanks a lot

**Edit: Solved.**

Show comments

Comment: We found two problems that kept the geometry columns from being mapped.

The first is that the correct topology library to use with Npgsql is: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite

Comment: The second one, that having overturned the data to PostgreSql with FME by default are created fields of type (Geometry,4326) instead of geometry that are the ones that EF interprets. 

So adding the correct nuget and making the update of the data types correct in the tables (ALTER TABLE schema.table ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE geometry;) solved problem